# How can i distribute an iOS product application through Appstore or using any other medium to multiple clients?

Tags: ios, app-store, ios-enterprise, app-distribution

We are having a product application and need to distribute it to multiple clients with different themes n colours. Currently we are uploading these multiple targets to our own apple itunes accounts and releasing on Appstore. These apps are publicly available and only the users purchasing the product can login to the application. Recently  submitted applications were rejected from appstore review due to the reason **"During our review, we still found that this app was designed for a specific business or organization and not for general distribution on the App Store. Business apps available on the App Store are meant for use by a wide variety of external customers around the world. "** .

How can i overcome this situation?.

Can we solve this issue by using a **Single** enterprise account?

Comment: Yes you can distribute multiple apps with one enterprise account.

Comment: If you have multiple independant client business, then it seems each would be required to enroll separately in the Enterprise program.  Instead, you might consider Apple's B2B program.

Comment: We are giving the apps to multiple companies and the employees in that companies are going to use this apps.. is there any issues? Like apple permissions??

Comment: If you are supplying the apps to anyone who isn't employed by your company then the enterprise program is not appropriate. As @hotpaw says, you should deliver a number of custom apps under the B2B program. See https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/304/

Comment: we are having clients in cyprus n client companies having employees in philippines n ukraine etc.. B2B is putting restrictions to distribute applications in some countries. Is this restriction is for accessing the application or for creating apple business manager ?? Any idea?